# Can I use Appollo GraphQl wiht Next14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I've wrapped my existing Next.Js 14 code with a ApolloProvider But it starts to refresh alot and gives the following error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Context is not available in this environment.

Here is the code:

```js
'use client'
    import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
    import client from "../../../apollo";
    export default function ApolloProviderComponent({
      children,
    }: Readonly<{
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }>) {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <div className="max-[90vw] px-[30px] py-[30px]">
            {children}
          </div>
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    }
```

Some More Code :)

```
    /*
  1. Creating connection with GraphQL
  2. Handling and showing GraphQL and network errors.
*/

// packages block
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink, HttpLink, from, Operation, NextLink } from "@apollo/client";
// components block

// utils and constants block
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { CONFLICT_EXCEPTION, INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN, INVALID_OR_EXPIRED_TOKEN_MESSAGE, NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION, PRECONDITION_FAILED_EXCEPTION, REQUEST_NOT_FOUND, TOKEN_INVALID, TOKEN_NOT_FOUND, UNAUTHENTICATED, UNAUTHORIZED } from "@/app/constants";


const handleLogout = () => {
  signOut()
}
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation: Operation, forward: NextLink) => {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  let token
  if (session) {
    token = session?.user?.data?.login?.accessToken
  }

  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });

  return forward(operation);
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/graphql`
}); handleLogout()

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }: any) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(
      ({ extensions }: any) => {
        if (extensions) {
          const { exception, code } = extensions;

          if (code === UNAUTHENTICATED) handleLogout()

          if (exception) {
            const { response } = exception as any

            if (response) {
              const { error, response: errorResponse } = response

              if (error && error !== REQUEST_NOT_FOUND && error !== NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION && error !== CONFLICT_EXCEPTION) {
                if (error === TOKEN_NOT_FOUND) {
                  console.log(INVALID_OR_EXPIRED_TOKEN_MESSAGE)
                } else
                  console.log(error)
              }

              if (errorResponse) {
                const { error: responseError, message } = errorResponse;

                if (message && message !== REQUEST_NOT_FOUND && message !== NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION && message !== CONFLICT_EXCEPTION) {
                  console.log(message)
                } else if (responseError && responseError !== REQUEST_NOT_FOUND && responseError !== NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION && responseError !== CONFLICT_EXCEPTION && responseError === PRECONDITION_FAILED_EXCEPTION) {
                  console.log(responseError)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        return null
      }
    );

    const [{ message }] = graphQLErrors;
    if (message === UNAUTHORIZED || message === TOKEN_INVALID || message === INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN) { }
  }

  if (networkError) console.log(networkError.message)
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: from([authMiddleware, errorLink, httpLink]),
});

export default client;
```

I was trying to configure apollo client graphql with next 14. Am i supposed to use the experimental package to work with app router?

Here's some more code:

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Provider from "./Provider";
import AppBar from "./components/AppBar";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "../../apollo";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: Readonly<{ children: React.ReactNode; }>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Provider>
            <AppBar />
            {children}
          </Provider>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is probably related to your Apollo client configs and their placement in `_app.*`; it's better to share the config, too.

Comment: Added "client" code

Comment: If you use the app router, you need the package for the app router. The app router uses experimental React features that cannot be supported by the normal Apollo Client at this time.